# Smoothest Function for Generating a Vector from 0 to 1

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, smooth-functions

I am working on a problem where I need to create a vector $ \mathbf{V} $ of dimension $ n + 1 $ such that $ \mathbf{V}[0] = 0 $ and $ \mathbf{V}[n] = 1 $. The vector should grow smoothly from $0$ to $1$. My idea is to find the "smoothest" function $ f(x) $ that grows from 0 to 1 over the interval $ [0, 1] $, and then sample this function $ n $ times to populate the vector.

1. What are some mathematical criteria for a function to be considered "smooth" in this context?
2. What functions $ f(x) $ satisfy these criteria and grow from 0 to 1 over the interval $ [0, 1] $?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your problem... Why do you need a smooth vector? A straight line going from $0$ to $1$ is smooth, as well as any polynomial function or an exponential function. Does it have to be monotonic? Strictly increasing?

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x^k}{n^k}$ for any positive $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\right)$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{n}-1}$

Comment: You should also explain what you mean by "smooth"... Do you mean a function that has many continuous derivatives (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)? Or are you using this term in an informal manner? Without explaining the motivation for this question, a precise answer cannot be formulated...

Comment: @DanielCunha Thank you for the suggested functions, I meant it in an informal manner, but it appears that a smooth function in an informal manner tends to have many continuous derivatives.

Comment: Is there a reason $f(x)=x$ is not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understood your question, but maybe a [smooth transition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) could do what are you aimming to achieve, like:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\qquad x\leq 0\\
1,\qquad x\geq 1\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x}\right)},\ 0<x<1
\end{cases}$$

Check it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hfkcqxxrnp)

Comment: +1 just because I could look at a desmos plot with minimal effort

Answer (score 0):

The function has to be continuous, differentiable and monotonic on the interval [0,1]. The "smoothest" function I could think of is a logistic function in the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-kx}}$

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the reason you want this function, one can not present a precise answer. There is a smooth activation function often used when we want to analyze a mechanical structure under a harmonic load. We use this smooth activation to slowly excite the structure, in order to have a better numerical behavior when integrating the response over time.

It is defined to have the following properties:

---

$$f(0) = 0$$

$$f'(0) = 0 \;\;\;\text{($f$ is smooth at 0)}$$

$$f''(0) = 0 \;\;\;\text{($f'$ is smooth at 0)}$$

$$f(1) = 1$$

$$f'(1) = 0 \;\;\;\text{($f$ is smooth at 1)}$$

$$f''(1) = 0 \;\;\;\text{($f'$ is smooth at 1)}$$

---

This information can be used to uniquely define a degree-$5$ polynomial:

$$f(t) = c_0 + c_1\,t + c_2\,t^2 + c_3\,t^3 + c_4\,t^4 + c_5\,t^5$$

$$f(0) = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{c_0 = 0}$$

$$f'(0) = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{c_1 = 0}$$

$$f''(0) = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{c_2 = 0}$$

$$f(1) = c_3 + c_4 + c_5 = 1$$

$$f'(1) = 3\,c_3 + 4\,c_4 + 5\,c_5 = 0$$

$$f''(1) = 6\,c_3 + 12\,c_4 + 20\,c_5 = 0$$

Solving the system for $c_3$, $c_4$ and $c_5$, we get:

$$\boxed{c_3 = 10}$$

$$\boxed{c_4 = -15}$$

$$\boxed{c_5 = 6}$$

---

Therefore, the activation function is given by:

$$\boxed{f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & ,\;\;\text{if}\;\;t < 0\hspace{1.3em}\\
t^3\,[6\,t^2 - 15\,t + 10] & ,\;\;\text{if} \;\;t\in[0,1]\\
1 & ,\;\;\text{if}\;\;t > 1\hspace{1.3em}
\end{array}\right.}$$

---

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9d0lcwnihp) you can see the plot for the function and its derivatives.

Comment: there is a typo in the last formula: its $15t$ instead of $16t$

Comment: Thank you @Joako!

Comment: Be careful with your example, since where it is non-constant, it is only smooth on $(0,\,1)$, and not in the whole domain, since its 3rd derivative is discontinuous, as shown in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xaby7qqq01). Non-constant Power series can't match smoothly constant values in a non-zero domain since it will violate the [Identity Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem). If you want a whole-domain smooth function that matches a constant value you will need a [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function).

Comment: As example, check my answer.

Comment: It is not $C^{\infty}$, but it is $C^{2}$. The author could not tell us much about the problem, so we have to speculate... As far as we know, $f(x)=x$ should do the job, I am just presenting another possible solution.